# Filtering out results based on length of reference number

Tags: reporting-services, duplicates, expression, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report, in report builder, where I am getting duplicate rows based on the reference number.

In the below example, is there anyway that I can remove any reference number that is longer than 9 digits using an expression, I've looked into using LEN but cant seem to make it work for me! I am very new to SQL and report builder.

[image: duplicate rows example]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Filter on either the Dataset or the object (table, chart...).

The Filter Expression would be the LEN of you field - `=LEN(Fields!HB-RENT-REF.Value)`

The Type would be `Integer`.

The Operator would be `<=`.

And the Value would be 9.

This would only allow records with a HB-RENT-REF field length of 9 or less.

[image]

[MS Docs: Dataset Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/add-a-filter-to-a-dataset-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Thanks guys, I've not had a chance to look at implementing these suggestions yet. I will have a crack on monday and let know the results, will probably try the expression first as like I said am new to report builder and not quite ready to do SQL statements cheers

Comment: thank you, im pretty sure that this solution has resolved my issue need someone else to check the results but the transaction amounts now look better. i had already tried something similar but on the row groups and an expression of =LEN(CStr(Fields!HB_RENT_REF.Value) where the type was integer and the operator was = to 9 but i think putting your expression on the Tablix has helped @CoderLee im sure your answer is just as valid but maybe a bit advanced for me at this time :) thanks to you both

Answer (score 0):

If you're using SQL scripts or procs to build your report, then you could simply include a WHERE clause that checks for if the length of your column, using the `LEN()` method, is less than or equal to your condition. So something along these lines:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM YourTable AS yt
WHERE LEN(yt.YourColumn) <= 9;
```

You will want to replace the * with the specific columns you want and use the appropriate tables too of course. But that's the general idea of checking for length in a WHERE.